# creating rows dynamically in the SQL output after a particular group

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data something like below in a temp table:

```
AccountID   Date          Product1   Product2  Product3
--------------------------------------------------------   
101         02/24/2019       3          4        5
101         02/20/2019       4          5        6
102         02/24/2019       5          1        2
102         02/20/2019       1          2        5
102         02/16/2019       2          3        2
103         02/24/2019       2          3        4
```

I want to get a total row after each account with total number of products ordered for a particular product accountwise

**Desired** output:

```
AccountID   Date          Product1   Product2  Product3
--------------------------------------------------------   
101         02/24/2019       3          4        5
101         02/20/2019       4          5        6
            total            7          9        11
102         02/24/2019       5          1        2
102         02/20/2019       1          2        5
102         02/16/2019       2          3        2  
            total            8          6        9
103         02/24/2019       2          3        4
            total            2          3        4
```

Note: number of rows under particular account are not constant

please guide me.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ROLLUP` to get the desired output.

```
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN date IS NULL THEN '' 
         ELSE Cast(accountid AS VARCHAR(10)) 
       END AS accountid, 
       CASE 
         WHEN date IS NULL THEN 'Total' 
         ELSE Cast(date AS VARCHAR(10)) 
       END AS date, 
       product1, 
       product2, 
       product3 
FROM   (SELECT accountid, 
               date, 
               Sum(product1) AS Product1, 
               Sum(product2) AS Product2, 
               Sum(product3) AS Product3 
        FROM   @mytable 
        GROUP  BY rollup( accountid, date ))t 
WHERE  accountid IS NOT NULL
```

**Output**

```
+-----------+------------+----------+----------+----------+
| accountid | date       | product1 | product2 | product3 |
+-----------+------------+----------+----------+----------+
| 101       | 2019-02-20 | 4        | 5        | 6        |
+-----------+------------+----------+----------+----------+
| 101       | 2019-02-24 | 3        | 4        | 5        |
+-----------+------------+----------+----------+----------+
|           | Total      | 7        | 9        | 11       |
+-----------+------------+----------+----------+----------+
| 102       | 2019-02-16 | 2        | 3        | 2        |
+-----------+------------+----------+----------+----------+
| 102       | 2019-02-20 | 1        | 2        | 5        |
+-----------+------------+----------+----------+----------+
| 102       | 2019-02-24 | 5        | 1        | 2        |
+-----------+------------+----------+----------+----------+
|           | Total      | 8        | 6        | 9        |
+-----------+------------+----------+----------+----------+
| 103       | 2019-02-24 | 2        | 3        | 4        |
+-----------+------------+----------+----------+----------+
|           | Total      | 2        | 3        | 4        |
+-----------+------------+----------+----------+----------+
```

[**Online Demo**](https://rextester.com/DGK45085)

Comment: thanks PSK for the quick reply.. is it possible to get one more row called as Price. i get price from another table by productid and this row should also be against each account, because price may differ for each account

AccountID   Date          Product1   Product2  Product3
--------------------------------------------------------   
               Price                 1          2        3
101         02/24/2019       3          4        5
101         02/20/2019       4          5        6
               total                  7          9        11

Comment: you can write a subquery in the select like select ...,(select price from newtable where id =producctid)

Comment: if you have another question, instead of updating the existing one, you can always raise another question, you will get better responses.

Comment: PSK.. any idea why the order has changed. eg. under accountid 101, in the sample data provided , we have 2019-02-24 as the first row and 2019-02-20 as the 2nd row, but after performing rollup the order has changed.. how do we get the original order?

Comment: does it make any difference?, by default group by rollup will order the data, if you are really concerned about the order you need convert date to varchar do some manipulation and convert it back to date which is not advisable

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189046/discussion-between-venkatesh-and-psk).

Answer (score 1):

Try doing a `GROUP BY` with `ROLLUP`:

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(AccountID, 0) AS account,
    COALESCE(Date, 'total') AS Date,
    SUM(Product1) AS Product1,
    SUM(Product2) AS Product2,
    SUM(Product3) AS Product3
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY ROLLUP (AccountID, Date);
```

[image]

### Demo

Comment: @PSK Your initial answer was wrong, so I decided to also answer.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply Tim